# skip declaring variable if condition not met terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I Am trying to create S3 bucket module, currently i am stuck with one scenario. For example user don't bucket to be encrypted then kms key shouldn't be created. It is working till here, how ever there is a variable `kms_policy`. Now even if i  set `encrypt_s3_bucket` false during validation it is asking me to pass variable.

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "mykey" {
  count = var.encrypt_s3_bucket ? 1:0
  description             = "This key is used to encrypt bucket objects"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation = false
  multi_region = false
  policy = var.encrypt_s3_bucket ? var.kms_policy : null
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "kms_policy" {
  type = string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to skip variable creation. Instead make a default value, and this way it will not ask you for the variable all the time.

```
variable "kms_policy" {
  default = null
  type = string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an implied dependency between two of your input variables: if `encrypt_s3_bucket` is true then `kms_policy` must be set, but if `encrypt_s3_bucket` is false then it need not be set.

In a situation like that, I would suggest combining both of these into a single variable so that it's clearer that they are strongly connected. For example:

```
variable "s3_bucket_encryption" {
  type = object({
    kms_policy = string
  })
  default = null
}
```

This declares a single variable called `s3_bucket_encryption` whose type constraint is for an object type with a `kms_policy` attribute. The user of this module can then choose either to leave that variable unset (`null`), or to set it to an object with a policy specified:

```
  s3_bucket_encryption = {
    kms_policy = "..."
  }
```

Notice that there's now no way to enable S3 bucket encryption *without* providing a policy, and also no way to provide a policy without enabling encryption.

Then to use this within your module:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "mykey" {
  count = var.s3_bucket_encryption != null ? 1 : 0

  description             = "This key is used to encrypt bucket objects"
  deletion_window_in_days = 10
  enable_key_rotation     = false
  multi_region            = false
  policy                  = var.s3_bucket_encryption.kms_policy
}
```